# Query organization with HotChocolate

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm trying to organize my query in such way

```
public class RootQueryType : ObjectType
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Include<UserQuery>().Name("userQuery");

            descriptor.Include<MessageQuery>().Name("messageQuery");
        }
    }
```

But in my Altair playground I end up with this:
[image: Altair Documentation]

There is no `userQuery`, but I still can query fields from it. I think that it is not the way Include should work and I'm looking for a way to get messageQuery and userQuery separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include merges all the fields of the included type into the current type. `Name` refers to the name of the current type. In order to get another level in your type just create a field that returns the new type.

Did you know that you do not need these type descriptors but can just express everything with pure C#.

```cs
public class Query 
{
    public UserQuery GetUsers() => new UserQuery();
}

public class UserQuery 
{
    ...
}
```

This will result in:

```
type Query {
  users: UserQuery
}

type UserQuery {
  # ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Include` returns the `IObjectTypeDescriptor`
So what you re doing is you are setting the name of `RootQueryType`

If I understand you correctly you would like to be able to query like this:

```
{
    userQuery {
      userName
    }
    messageQuery {
      message
    }
}
```

```cs
public class RootQueryType : ObjectType
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Field("userQuery").Resolve(new UserQuery())
            descriptor.Field("messageQuery").Resolve(new MessageQuery())
        }
    }
```

In case you want to actually combine the types, and be able to create a query like this:

```
  
{ 
    userName  
    message 
}
```

You can use `ObjectTypeExtensions`

```cs
[ExtendObjectType("Query")]
public class UserQuery {
    public string GetUserName() => ...
  
}
[ExtendObjectType("Query")]
public class MessageQuery {
    public string Message() => ...
  
}
```

You can then do

```cs
services.AddGraphQLServer()
   .AddQueryType(x => x.Name("Query"))
   .AddTypeExtension<UserQuery>()
   .AddTypeExtension<MessageQuery>()
```